# Intellisense: argument of type "HWND" is incompatible with parameter of type "rawData::HWND"

Tags: c++, wndproc, hwnd

I have been improving a class that I have been working on and one of those things is creating libraries to handle certain tasks that are not really needed to be seen in my main project. However when I call the class and instantiate the library I just created I get:

> Intellisense: argument of type "HWND" is incompatible with parameter
>   of type "rawData::HWND"

This is happening  when I call a method from the library and pass these arguments ( the error is in the first argument):

```
// register the window for touch instead of gestures
   rawData::RegisterTouchWindow(hWnd, 0);
```

The complete code for this here:

```
   //Creates the main window
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{

  WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        800, 600,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

   if (!hWnd) {
      MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
   }   
   // register the window for touch instead of gestures
   /*ERROR HERE*/rawTData::RegisterTouchWindow(hWnd, 0);/*ERROR HERE*/  

   // the following code initializes the points
   for (int i=0; i< MAXPOINTS; i++){
     points[i][0] = -1;
     points[i][1] = -1;
     idLookup[i]  = -1;
   }  

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

I have gone to a few websites and they suggest using "this->" to specify which variable you are pointing to but nothing shows when I try it. It's why I came here to see if anyone has ran into this situation. Any little help would b most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Also, here is the source of my library class:

```
#ifndef RAWTOUCHDATA_H
#define RAWTOUCHDATA_H

#pragma once
namespace rawTData
{
//#define __in                                          __allowed(on_parameter)
#if (defined(_M_IX86) || defined(_M_IA64) || defined(_M_AMD64)) && !defined(MIDL_PASS)
#define DECLSPEC_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#endif

//
// Define API decoration for direct importing of DLL references.
//
#if !defined(_USER32_)
#define WINUSERAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#define WINABLEAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#else
#define WINUSERAPI
#define WINABLEAPI
#endif

#ifndef NO_STRICT
#ifndef STRICT
#define STRICT 1
#endif
#endif /* NO_STRICT */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#ifndef WINVER                  // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows 7.
#define WINVER 0x0601           // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT            // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows 7.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601     // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif

//
// The following types are guaranteed to be signed and 32 bits wide.
//
typedef signed int LONG32, *PLONG32;

//
// The following types are guaranteed to be unsigned and 32 bits wide.
//
typedef unsigned int ULONG32, *PULONG32;
typedef unsigned int DWORD32, *PDWORD32;

#if !defined(_W64)
#if !defined(__midl) && (defined(_X86_) || defined(_M_IX86)) && _MSC_VER >= 1300
#define _W64 __w64
#else
#define _W64
#endif
#endif

//
// The INT_PTR is guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer.  Its
// size with change with pointer size (32/64).  It should be used
// anywhere that a pointer is cast to an integer type. UINT_PTR is
// the unsigned variation.
//
// __int3264 is intrinsic to 64b MIDL but not to old MIDL or to C compiler.
//
#if ( 501 < __midl )

    typedef [public] __int3264 INT_PTR, *PINT_PTR;
    typedef [public] unsigned __int3264 UINT_PTR, *PUINT_PTR;

    typedef [public] __int3264 LONG_PTR, *PLONG_PTR;
    typedef [public] unsigned __int3264 ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;

#else  // midl64
// old midl and C++ compiler

#if defined(_WIN64)
    typedef __int64 INT_PTR, *PINT_PTR;
    typedef unsigned __int64 UINT_PTR, *PUINT_PTR;

    typedef __int64 LONG_PTR, *PLONG_PTR;
    typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;

    #define __int3264   __int64

#else
    typedef _W64 int INT_PTR, *PINT_PTR;
    typedef _W64 unsigned int UINT_PTR, *PUINT_PTR;

    typedef _W64 long LONG_PTR, *PLONG_PTR;
    typedef _W64 unsigned long ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;

    #define __int3264   __int32

#endif
#endif // midl64

//
// Define API decoration for direct importing system DLL references.
//
#if !defined(_NTSYSTEM_)
#define NTSYSAPI     DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#define NTSYSCALLAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#else
#define NTSYSAPI
#if defined(_NTDLLBUILD_)
#define NTSYSCALLAPI
#else
#define NTSYSCALLAPI DECLSPEC_ADDRSAFE
#endif
#endif

//
// Basics
//
#ifndef VOID
#define VOID void
typedef char CHAR;
typedef short SHORT;
typedef long LONG;
#if !defined(MIDL_PASS)
typedef int INT;
#endif
#endif

#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0500
#endif /* WINVER */

/*
 * BASETYPES is defined in ntdef.h if these types are already defined
 */
#ifndef BASETYPES
#define BASETYPES
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
typedef ULONG *PULONG;
typedef unsigned short USHORT;
typedef USHORT *PUSHORT;
typedef unsigned char UCHAR;
typedef UCHAR *PUCHAR;
typedef char *PSZ;
#endif  /* !BASETYPES */

#define MAX_PATH          260

#ifndef NULL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL    0
#else
#define NULL    ((void *)0)
#endif
#endif

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE               0
#endif

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE                1
#endif

#ifndef IN
#define IN
#endif

#ifndef OUT
#define OUT
#endif

#ifndef OPTIONAL
#define OPTIONAL
#endif

#undef far
#undef near
#undef pascal

#define far
#define near
#if (!defined(_MAC)) && ((_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED))
#define pascal __stdcall
#else
#define pascal
#endif

#if defined(DOSWIN32) || defined(_MAC)
#define cdecl _cdecl
#ifndef CDECL
#define CDECL _cdecl
#endif
#else
#define cdecl
#ifndef CDECL
#define CDECL
#endif
#endif

#ifdef _MAC
#define CALLBACK    PASCAL
#define WINAPI      CDECL
#define WINAPIV     CDECL
#define APIENTRY    WINAPI
#define APIPRIVATE  CDECL
#ifdef _68K_
#define PASCAL      __pascal
#else
#define PASCAL
#endif
#elif (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)
#define CALLBACK    __stdcall
#define WINAPI      __stdcall
#define WINAPIV     __cdecl
#define APIENTRY    WINAPI
#define APIPRIVATE  __stdcall
#define PASCAL      __stdcall
#else
#define CALLBACK
#define WINAPI
#define WINAPIV
#define APIENTRY    WINAPI
#define APIPRIVATE
#define PASCAL      pascal
#endif

#ifdef _M_CEE_PURE
#define WINAPI_INLINE  __clrcall
#else
#define WINAPI_INLINE  WINAPI
#endif

#undef FAR
#undef  NEAR
#define FAR                 far
#define NEAR                near
#ifndef CONST
#define CONST               const
#endif

typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
typedef int                 BOOL;
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
typedef unsigned short      WORD;
typedef float               FLOAT;
typedef FLOAT               *PFLOAT;
typedef BYTE near           *PBYTE;
typedef BYTE far            *LPBYTE;
typedef int near            *PINT;
typedef int far             *LPINT;
typedef WORD near           *PWORD;
typedef WORD far            *LPWORD;
typedef long far            *LPLONG;
typedef DWORD near          *PDWORD;
typedef DWORD far           *LPDWORD;
typedef void far            *LPVOID;
typedef CONST void far      *LPCVOID;

typedef int                 INT;
typedef unsigned int        UINT;
typedef unsigned int        *PUINT;

#if(WINVER >= 0x0601)
#define WM_TOUCH                        0x0240
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0601 */

//
// Handle to an Object
//
#ifdef STRICT
typedef void *HANDLE;
#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000)
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__; typedef struct name##__ *name
#else
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
#endif
#else
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) typedef HANDLE name
#endif

typedef HANDLE *PHANDLE;
#ifndef WIN_INTERNAL
DECLARE_HANDLE            (HWND);
DECLARE_HANDLE            (HHOOK);
#ifdef WINABLE
DECLARE_HANDLE            (HEVENT);
#endif
#endif

typedef const RECTL FAR* LPCRECTL;
typedef struct tagPOINT
{
    LONG  x;
    LONG  y;
} POINT, *PPOINT, NEAR *NPPOINT, FAR *LPPOINT;
typedef struct _POINTL      /* ptl  */
{
    LONG  x;
    LONG  y;
} POINTL, *PPOINTL;

typedef struct tagSIZE
{
    LONG        cx;
    LONG        cy;
} SIZE, *PSIZE, *LPSIZE;

typedef SIZE               SIZEL;
typedef SIZE               *PSIZEL, *LPSIZEL;

typedef struct tagPOINTS
{
#ifndef _MAC
    SHORT   x;
    SHORT   y;
#else
    SHORT   y;
    SHORT   x;
#endif
} POINTS, *PPOINTS, *LPPOINTS;

#if(WINVER >= 0x0601)

/*
 * Touch Input defines and functions
 */

/*
 * Touch input handle
 */
DECLARE_HANDLE(HTOUCHINPUT);

typedef struct tagTOUCHINPUT {
    LONG x;
    LONG y;
    HANDLE hSource;
    DWORD dwID;
    DWORD dwFlags;
    DWORD dwMask;
    DWORD dwTime;
    ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
    DWORD cxContact;
    DWORD cyContact;
} TOUCHINPUT, *PTOUCHINPUT;
typedef TOUCHINPUT const * PCTOUCHINPUT;

/*
 * Conversion of touch input coordinates to pixels
 */
#define TOUCH_COORD_TO_PIXEL(l)         ((l) / 100)

/*
 * Touch input flag values (TOUCHINPUT.dwFlags)
 */
#define TOUCHEVENTF_MOVE            0x0001
#define TOUCHEVENTF_DOWN            0x0002
#define TOUCHEVENTF_UP              0x0004
#define TOUCHEVENTF_INRANGE         0x0008
#define TOUCHEVENTF_PRIMARY         0x0010
#define TOUCHEVENTF_NOCOALESCE      0x0020
#define TOUCHEVENTF_PEN             0x0040
#define TOUCHEVENTF_PALM            0x0080

/*
 * Touch input mask values (TOUCHINPUT.dwMask)
 */
#define TOUCHINPUTMASKF_TIMEFROMSYSTEM  0x0001  // the dwTime field contains a system generated value
#define TOUCHINPUTMASKF_EXTRAINFO       0x0002  // the dwExtraInfo field is valid
#define TOUCHINPUTMASKF_CONTACTAREA     0x0004  // the cxContact and cyContact fields are valid

WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
ScreenToClient(
    HWND hWnd,
    LPPOINT lpPoint);

WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
GetTouchInputInfo(
    HTOUCHINPUT hTouchInput,               // input event handle; from touch message lParam
    UINT cInputs,                          // number of elements in the array
    PTOUCHINPUT pInputs,  // array of touch inputs
    int cbSize);                           // sizeof(TOUCHINPUT)

WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
CloseTouchInputHandle(
    HTOUCHINPUT hTouchInput);                   // input event handle; from touch message lParam

/*
 * RegisterTouchWindow flag values
 */
#define TWF_FINETOUCH       (0x00000001)
#define TWF_WANTPALM        (0x00000002)

WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
RegisterTouchWindow(
    HWND hwnd,
    ULONG ulFlags);

WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
UnregisterTouchWindow(
    HWND hwnd);

WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
IsTouchWindow(
    HWND hwnd,
    PULONG pulFlags);

#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0601 */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif  /* __cplusplus */
}
#endif //RAWTOUCHDATA_H
```

Comment: Looks like you may have put an `#include` of some Windows API file inside a class or namespace.  It thinks the `HWND` type belongs to your `rawData` class or namespace (I can't actually tell which it is without seeing that code).

Comment: It sounds like the rawData class declares its own HWND type when is different than the scopeless one declared by the Windows headers.

Comment: @SamCristall: Hi, the file is included within the header file of my class.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter Yes within the RawData class is its own HWND type

Comment: @ManuelMangual You can't define your own `HWND` type and expect the Windows APIs to understand what it is.  Can you post the RawData class source?

Comment: @SamCristall I added the source code

Comment: @ManuelMangual Did you just copy/paste half of windows.h into your own header in a custom namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting everything in your own `namespace rawTData`, you've declared all of those types to belong to `rawTData`.  `HWND` is a Windows API type, and is *not* equivalent to your definition (which is `rawTData::HWND`)  Namespaces are not simply for wrapping a bunch of code you don't want Intellisense to show, they "hide" names in a directory-like structure.  A simple fix is to move the `namespace rawTData {` down to above your own declarations but it begs the question:  why are you wrapping *everything* in `namespace rawTData`?

It looks like you've cut and pasted a bunch of `Windows.h` definitions into your own namespace.  You really should just include the appropriate file.  If that doesn't work there are likely other problems that need solving, and you shouldn't cut around it by copy-pasting like this.